# tar file much bigger than original files with use -T option and file list. Why?

Tags: gzip, tar

Now I'm testing tar commands.

I run the 2 command like below.

```
tar zcvf test1.tar.gz -C ./tar_dir .
tar zcvf test2.tar.gz -C ./tar_dir -T /file_list.txt
```

tar_dir size is about 200MB and has about 10000 files. file_list.txt has all file list of tar_dir dir with the relative path. so test1.tar.gz and test2.tar.gz have same files. but Size is too diffrent. test1.tar.gz is about 130MB and test2.tar.gz is about 1.5GB.

I can't understand that. I'm sure test1.tar.gz and test2.tar.gz has same files. why these size of two files different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the tar files do not actually contain the same files...Maybe there's an error with the paths in the file_list.txt...

You can do something like the below command to find out what's in test2.tar.gz and not in test1.tar.gz

## sdiff -s <(tar -tf test1.tar.gz| sed 's/^.///g'| sort) <(tar -tf test2.tar.gz | sort)

THe "sed" for test1.tar.gz is meant to remove the "./" in front f the files in order to relevantly compare the two tar file listings and the sort is to order them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank!. I found the problem. you're right. if /tar_dir has /tar_dir/inner_dir/test, i write the file list like this "/tar_dir/inner_dir" and "/tar_dir/inner_dir/test". And so /tar_dir/inner_dir/test file duplicatied. This file duplication makes bigger tar.gz file than original. thanks!

Comment: Glad to help :)